# code executes before getting return value

Tags: android, onesignal

I am trying to display alertdialog after checking some function return value. But alertdialog code is always executing before other function return true. while in debugging  it runs perfectly.

```
if(!isServiceComplete()){
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Complete Service");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent positiveActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ServiceActivity.class);
                    startActivity(positiveActivity);
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }
```

> and the function is:

```
public boolean isServiceComplete() {
    serviceComplete =  false;
    try {
        OneSignal.getTags(new OneSignal.GetTagsHandler() {
            @Override
            public void tagsAvailable(final JSONObject tags) {
                if (tags.has("status")) {
                    serviceComplete = true;
                } else {

                    serviceComplete = false;

                }
            }

        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return serviceComplete;
}
```

Please tell me how to wait for execution of function before alertdialog. Thanks

Comment: You are making async call. This is the expected behavior for async calls.

Comment: You must add callbacks instead of what you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks for your input as m not able to fully write independently any example or rewrite of this would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not much into async calls and callbacks, I'll learn it, but as of now I called function in other place in activity.

Like I placed

`isServiceComplete()` in `OnCreate` method and changed `if` condition to

```
if(!serviceComplete){...}
```

Now is working fine